# Asynchronously download images for ListView on Android: why so complicated?

Tags: android, listview, asynchronous

I wanted to understand what is the proper way to display a list of images using ListView while asynchronously downloading them in background.

I've read the [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) on this topic. In order to solve concurrency issues when multiple download tasks for the same ImageView are requested, they create a new `AsyncDrawable` class which holds a weak reference to the download task.

Whenever a new download task on ImageView already being downloaded is requested, the existing task (extracted from AsyncDrawable) is cancelled.

The question is: why couldn't they just use `WeakHashMap<ImageView, Task>` to store a list of task per ImageView for the same purpose without introducing new classes?

Comment: sounds to me like you're trying to do a lazyloading in your `ListView`.. if so may you be you should check [this library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: they could ... but where WeakHashMap<ImageView, Task> would be anchored?

Comment: @Selvin, a static field inside `BitmapWorkerTask`? 
In `BitmapWorkerTask` constructor they can check and cancel already running task as well as register the current task.
I suspect no multithreading issues, cause it is always invoked on UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

> why couldn't they just use WeakHashMap to store a list of task per ImageView for the same purpose without introducing new classes?

The intent behind the tutorial using AsyncDrawable appears to be based off of Separation of Concerns, or a similar principle.

Essentially, you break out your application components, so they are not referencing each other.

In the example, you would get something like this hierarchy:

```
Activity -> ListView -> Adapter -> Row -> ImageView -> AsyncDrawable <-> Task
```

Now you don't need to manage that drawable in different places. With the hash map, you'd get something more like this.

```
Activity -> ListView -> Adapter -> Row -> ImageView(1) -> Drawable <- Task(2)
                     -> HashMap<ImageView(1), Task(2)>
```

Not all of a sudden, your hierarchy is non-linear. It becomes less maintainable over time, and if you ever change what your image view is showing, now you have to change your code in several different places, instead of just changing the Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try `Android-Universal-Image-Loader` lib for Asynchronously download images/ Image Loading

try this lib and example .

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImagePagerActivity.java

Tutorial

http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-android-library

Hope this might helpful...

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted to know how it actually works under the surface. Since i am new to both Java and Android, i started from Android tutorials.

Comment: if your using a ListView with images , the you have to go with CustomAdapter for that ListView., where in the getView of the Adapter your creating a view for Each row of the listview, check this link http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-image-listview.html